# LISP how to call an object from a variable after taking out the name of the object from another variable

Tags: object, lisp, common-lisp

I am still very beginner in LISP and hope that you all could give me some suggestions on how to solve the following problem.

```
(CG-USER(1):defstruct Test()
        (TestValue  10)
        (TestChild 'none)
        )
TEST

CG-USER(2): (defun testvalue(item)
         (slot-value item 'TESTCHILD))
TESTVALUE

CG-USER(3):(setf TestObject(make-Test :TestChild '(TestObject2 B C)))
#S(TEST :NIL NIL :TESTVALUE 10 :TESTCHILD (TESTOBJECT2 B C))

CG-USER(4): (setf TestObject2(make-Test :TestChild '(D E F)))
#S(TEST :NIL NIL :TESTVALUE 10 :TESTCHILD (D E F))

CG-USER(5): (setf aaa (car (testvalue TestObject)))
TESTOBJECT2

CG-USER(6): (testvalue aaa)
Error: The slot TESTCHILD is missing from the object TESTOBJECT2 of class #<BUILT-IN-CLASS         SYMBOL> during
   operation SLOT-VALUE
[condition type: PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

The following is my code. As you can see, I am trying to read the details in the object `TestObject2` through the function `testvalue` . My main purpose is to able to determine the name of the object (`TestObject2`) from the another object first (in this case, `TestObject`) as I do not know the name of the name `TestObject2` yet.

But however, once I managed to successfully retrieve the name `TestObject2` , when I try to access the elements inside the object (`TestObject2`) , it no longer identify the variable holding `TestObject2` (in this case, "aaa") as an object. Thus, it could not read the `testvalue` of it, resulting in the error.

I am very beginner at LISP and I could not figure out on how to solve this. It would be really great if anyone could provide a sample solution for this. Thanks.

P/S: Also, may I ask what is the `NIL NIL` in this line? And any way to remove it?

```
#S(TEST :NIL NIL :TESTVALUE 10 :TESTCHILD (D E F))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Second question:**

```
(defstruct Test()
  (TestValue  10)
  (TestChild 'none))
```

Let's format above slightly different:

```
(defstruct Test        ; the structure has a name `TEST`
  ()                   ; the first slot is named `NIL`
  (TestValue  10)      ; the second slot is named `TESTVALUE`
  (TestChild 'none))   ; the third slot is named `TESTCHILD`
```

So, it makes sense to remove the first slot... ;-) and we get:

```
(defstruct Test        ; the structure has a name `TEST`
  (TestValue  10)      ; the first slot is named `TESTVALUE`
  (TestChild 'none))   ; the second slot is named `TESTCHILD`
```

**First question**:

`TESTOBJECT2` is a symbol. If the symbol has a value, you can retrieve it with the function `SYMBOL-VALUE`.

```
(symbol-value 'testobject2)
```

Generally you want to slim your code a bit:

```
CL-USER 42 > (defstruct test
               (value  10)
               (child 'none))
TEST
```

In above we don't need the `test` prefix. `DEFSTRUCT` already creates accessors with `TEST-` as the prefix.

```
CL-USER 43 > (setf test-object (make-test :child '(test-object2 b c)))
#S(TEST :VALUE 10 :CHILD (TEST-OBJECT2 B C))
```

Note that in your example and in above code, the `:child` is not a structure. It is just a list of three symbols.

```
CL-USER 44 > (setf test-object2 (make-test :child '(d e f)))
#S(TEST :VALUE 10 :CHILD (D E F))
```

Again, the child of above is a list of three symbols.

```
CL-USER 45 > (setf aaa (car (test-child test-object)))
TEST-OBJECT2
```

Above: The first of that list is the symbol `TEST-OBJECT2`.

```
CL-USER 46 > (test-value (symbol-value aaa))
10
```

Above: we can retrieve the symbol value of the symbol `TEST-OBJECT2`, which is the value of the variable `AAA`.

Comment: Got it. :) However, can you please suggest any way to improve the other question of mine? :) Any way to change the code or to improve to access the elements inside the (TestObject2) ?